# How can I make logical drive/folder appear as virtual removable drive in Windows 8?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-8-preview

I want to test the "Windows to go" feature of Windows 8.

But I have no 16 GB drive.

How can I make logical drive/folder appear as virtual removable drive?

Answer (score 0):

There is the `subst` command.

```
    Associates a path with a drive letter.

SUBST [drive1: [drive2:]path]
SUBST drive1: /D

  drive1:        Specifies a virtual drive to which you want to assign a path.
  [drive2:]path  Specifies a physical drive and path you want to assign to
                 a virtual drive.
  /D             Deletes a substituted (virtual) drive.

Type SUBST with no parameters to display a list of current virtual drives.
```

However I don't think this makes it look like a removeable drive in `diskmgmt.msc`.

Comment: So... this is not an answer. The main aim is to make it appear as a  removable drive.

Comment: Yep, this doesn't work. Subst applies a DriveType of "Fixed" - eg no difference to an internal HDD